# How to merge some lines in awk?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I want to merge some rows in this file.

file.txt looks like this:

```
Adr R/W cnt
123 R   6
123 W   5
124 R   7
125 W   8
130 W   11
130 R   12
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Adr W   R
123 5   6
124 0   7
125 8   0
130 11  12
```

I have tried this so far:

```
awk '{a=$1; b=$2; c=$3; getline; d=$1; e=$2; f=$3;
    if(a==d && b=="W")
        print a " " c " " f;
    else if(a==d && b=="R")
        print a " " f " " c;
    else if (a!=d && b=="W")
        print a " " c " 0";
    else if(a!=d && b=="R")
        print a " 0 " c;}' file.txt
```

Comment: @jayant awk '{a=$1; b=$2; c=$3; getline; d=$1; e=$2; f=$3;if(a==d && b=="W")print a " " c " " f;else if(a==d && b=="R")print a " " f " " c;else if (a!=d && b=="W")print a " " c " 0";else if(a!=d && b=="R")print a " 0 " c;}' file.txt

Comment: Thanks. please feel free to edit your question and add what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

This uses GNU awk's [array of arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) feature:

```
gawk '
  NR>1 {val[$1][$2] = $3} 
  END {
    print "Adr W R"
    for (id in val) print id, 0 + val[id]["W"], 0 + val[id]["R"]
  }
' file.txt | column -t
```

```
Adr  W   R
123  5   6
124  0   7
125  8   0
130  11  12
```

Adding zero to an undefined value returns the number zero.

Comment: I think your solution does not guarantee the ordering of the output. Associative arrays in awk do not necessarily preserve ordering (as far as i know). When I run your code my output is  
`Adr  W   R  
130  11  12  
123  5   6  
124  0   7  
125  8   0`  
So, I rewrote the 5th line in your example and changed it to:  
`{for (id in val) print id, 0 + val[id]["W"], 0 + val[id]["R"] | "sort -k1n" }`  

Then, it works for me.

Comment: true about the ordering. Don't need to call out to sort though: since this is specifically gawk, add `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` before the for loop. ([docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html))